# What is the call limit of google maps on search using url http://maps.google.com/maps?q=<address>

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I will not use google map API.
In my website I just want to pass address to the url http://maps.google.com/maps?q= and open a popup window to show when address is clicked. 
I believe, there wont be any limit as user would be passing request through their browser and google can't trace the request generated from the host website. Am I correct ? Or is there any kind of limitation to arise in this case ?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a limit to calls to just maps.google.com, but there are limits when using the API.

I found this information in the documentation for the google maps api:
Usage Limits

The Google Geocoding API has the following limits in place:

Users of the free API:
2500 requests per 24 hour period.
5 requests per second.

Google Maps API for Work customers:
100 000 requests per 24 hour period.
10 requests per second.

reference - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/